# What does 'diope' mean in the poem 'Pediatric Reflection' by Ogden Nash?

Tags: poetry, wordplay, ogden-nash

"Pediatric Reflection" by Ogden Nash

> Many an infant that screams like a calliope
> Could be soothed by a little attention to its diope.

What does "diope" mean here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ogden Nash was fond of the humorous effect created by employing a rhyme that only works if you distort the pronunciation of one of the words, an effect that he signalled by a deliberate mis-spelling. Here are three examples, with glosses for the mis-spelled words:

> Better yet, if called by a panther,
> Don't anther.†
>
> <sub>Ogden Nash (1941). ‘[The Panther](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.77757/page/n87/mode/2up)’. In *The Face is Familiar*, p. 64. New York: Garden City.</sub>
>
> <sub>† answer</sub>

> A girl who is bespectacled,
> She may not get her nectacled.†
> But safety pins and bassinets
> Await the girl who fascinets.‡
>
> <sub>‘[Lines Written to Console Those Ladies Distressed by the Lines “Men Seldom Make Passes, etc.”](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.77757/page/n157/mode/2up)’ In Nash, p. 134.</sub>
>
> <sub>† neck tickled ‡ fascinates.</sub>

> A bit of talcum
> Is always walcum.†
>
> <sub>‘[Reflection on Babies](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.77757/page/n345/mode/2up)’. In Nash, p. 323.</sub>
>
> <sub>† welcome</sub>

So in the couplet quoted in the question, “diope” is a mis-spelling of “diaper” that makes it rhyme with “calliope”.

A [calliope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calliope_(music)) is a steam-driven organ, named after the ancient Greek muse [Calliope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calliope), and notorious for its volume: Wikipedia says, “some small calliopes are audible for miles”. The word should be pronounced /kəˈlaɪəpi/ with four syllables, not /ˈkæliˌoʊp/ with three, for Nash’s joke to work.

[image: Ornate four-wheeled carriage drawn by two white horses and driven by man with red military-style jacket and blue trousers. The side of the carriage is cut away to reveal a woman seated at an organ keyboard connected to a semi-circular bank of whistles and a large cylindrical boiler.]
<sub>1874 poster: “Calliope, the wonderful operonicon or steam car of the muses”. [Library of Congress, digital ID pga.01335](http://loc.gov/pictures/resource/pga.01335/).</sub>

Comment: ... a rhyme that works only if you know that calliope is pronounced with four syllables, /kəˈlaɪ ə pi/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was pronouncing calliope as ca-li -ope where ope rhymes with pope. Now that I know that it is pronounced as /kəˈlaɪ ə pi/ , the rhyme does make much more sense.